# PHP Caching scripts

Tags: php, caching, ini

I'm having a problem with PHP or Apache. It is caching webpages.

I'm trying to develop under Ubuntu Server and Apache with PHP 5. I have problems with the page being cached: I'm making changes and I can't see them. Even if I remove the entire script and put an echo 'HI'; it isn't showing.

How could I stop pages from being cached?

If I stop apache and start it again, pages are shown good.

Seen session.cache_expire  but doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not your browser?  Turn off caching on your browser, or (in some browsers like Chrome and Firefox) `ctrl F5` will reload the page from the server.

Comment: Yes it isn't my browser. I got a blank page and couldn't get out of there even if I put echo 'Hi'; only. I opened the same script from a virtual machine and got the same result.

Comment: When I try to open from IE in the title it says 500 Internal Server Error. :S

Answer (score 0):

If response status says `500 Internal Server Error.` There is an error in your new code, and the browser displays the old cache. Double check your new code, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not caching results but you have error_reporting and/or display errors disabled so you are getting a blank page.

You should set this params in your php.ini:

display_errors: On
error_reporting: E_ALL
log_errors: On

More info you can find [here](http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting):